# Passing event listener parameters with native javascript?

Tags: javascript, events, dom

I have implement three jQuery-like functions for controling my custom events (i can't using jquery in my project :-():

```
var Events = {
   on: function(evt, fn) {
       document.addEventListener(evt, fn);
   },
   off: function() {
       document.removeEventListener(evt, fn);
   },
   trigger: function(evt, params) {
        var event; // The custom event that will be created
            if (document.createEvent) {
                event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
                event.eventName = evt;
                event.initEvent(evt, true, true);
                event.data = params;
                window.dispatchEvent(event);
            } else {
                event = document.createEventObject();
                event.eventName = evt;
                event.eventType = evt;
                event.data = params;
                window.fireEvent("on" + event.eventType, event);
            }
   }
}
```

When i using my observer implementation i have:

```
Events.on('custom', function(e) {
       console.log(e.data); // output [5,10,15]
});

Events.trigger('custom', [5, 10, 15]);
```

But i need modify my trigger function to call listener with additional parameters after event object. Something like [jquery.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) function with **extraParameters** attribute. For my example:

```
Events.on('custom', function(e, a, b, c) {
     console.log(a, b, c); //output [5,10,15]
});

Events.trigger('custom', [5,10,15]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    var event = new CustomEvent('build', { 'detail': 'test' });


    // Listen for the event.
    document.addEventListener('build', function (events) {
        console.log(events.detail)
    }, false);

    // Dispatch the event.
    document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

In this way you can pass data to custom created event

[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

**EDIT:**

```
if (window.CustomEvent) {
  var event = new CustomEvent('my-event', {detail: {some: 'data'}});
} else {
  var event = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
  event.initCustomEvent('my-event', true, true, {some: 'data'});
}
```

this is jquery equivalent to trigger

Comment: I got the results with `event.detail` but i need got it with extraParameters as listener function arguments.... It's important for me for one reason: parameters must be passed as array of arguments (not as object)!

Comment: @xercool then pass all the data in the detail as an object `{ 'detail': {'key1': value1, 'key2': 'value2' } }`

Comment: it doesn't good for me. I need just imitate jquery.trigger() as i wrote in my question. I will have to rewrite a lot of code to change this approach. Sorry

Comment: I doubt it is the only way. its compatible with IE 9+

Comment: @strikers it is the only way. Now params defined as arguments using extraParameters in all listeners.